# Embeded controller called from twig - data from another

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm new to symfony and want to create a `third party bundle` to render HTML templates, so to have all twig files into it. In fact I created it, and I can use the template from my `AppBundle`.

Now, in the third party template I have a header with a drop-down with some notifications (eg: high server load..). I want to render these notification by embedding a controller into the twig template (so, I'll call *`render(controller())`*). Because I want to reuse this function I want to put the controller into the `third party bundle`, because I can have more projects with this function.

How can I pass `data` to this controller, or, how can I tell this controller that when it is called by the twig extension (`*render(controller()*`) ) to get data from another source?
I don't want to put the "data logic" into the third party controller because in one project the notification "list" may be into a database, in another may be into a JSON object.

> 1. AppBundle calls the third party twig template from a route
> 2. The twig template has a dropdown, to render the dropdown it calls a controller into the thid party bundle
> 3. The called controller renders some twig parts that are present into the third party twig template, but I don't want that it reads data (query mysql) but "ask" to an interface that I pass from the
>      AppBundle

Is it possible?

I know that I could "call" and "fill" the template from the `AppBundle`, but I would like to have a "tool" that renders my notifications and in the `AppBundle` have only some sort of interface to "send data", so to write some little code in other projects.

Comment: create another method in this controller ;-)

Comment: Ok. I create a method in the third party Controller, and I call it from the twig template. But I can't understand how this method can read data without quering or else but asking data from another "ipotetical" controller in another Bundle!

Comment: Instead of a controller consider gathering your data via a twig extension: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html.  Your application can then configure the extension to return the data in the desired format.

Comment: Hi cerad. I have to write a twig extension into the third party bundle? I use a the embeded controller like this situation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html but the controller is in the third party bundle and I don't whant to query for recent articles but "ask" and "receive" recent articles to/from main application.

Comment: Basically yes.  You will need some sort of interface that main application will implement for the ask part.  You would then inject this asker object into your 3rd party twig extension.  Somewhat advanced concept.  Make sure you have a good understanding about dependency injection, containers, configuration and twig extensions.  By the way, use @cerad if you reply and I'll get a notification.  I just happened to see your latest comment.